# PHP Left bit shift issue on 32 bit

Tags: php, bit-shift

I am running into the issue where I need to do a << on a 32 bit machine and the number is already pretty big. If I shift on this big number the answer is incorrect, any way I can get past this?

I am pretty sure that the laptop is running Windows7 64 bit but PHP_INT_MAX produces 2147483647. Is there any way to set the php to use 64 bits? I am running XAMPP server on this laptop and I have to do some bit shifting on numbers, if the numbers are shifted too many times I get an incorrect answer.

Thanks in advance. 
Jack

Answer (score 1):

[From the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

So no, you can't set it to use 64 bits.

It seems like the [GMP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php) might be what you need. Someone has posted a tip on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) for doing bitwise shifting with them:

> Also, for those who wish to do bitwise shifting, it's quite simple.. to shift left, just multiply the number by pow(2,x), and to shift right, divide by pow(2,x).

```
<?php 
function gmp_shiftl($x,$n) { // shift left 
  return(gmp_mul($x,gmp_pow(2,$n))); 
} 

function gmp_shiftr($x,$n) { // shift right 
  return(gmp_div($x,gmp_pow(2,$n))); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to say the same thing, showing a [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) code sample instead.

Comment: I have no idea how that is going to help me? If I am limited to 32 bit and I call:
$bitString = $bitString << 5;
where $bitString is 10183165152 I am pretty much stuck? Am I missing something in your suggestion?

Comment: You would use GMP numbers, which are arbitrary precision, rather than php's fixed size ints. You can create GMP numbers with [GMP init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php). Also, as @PleaseStand suggested, you could also use bcmath to accomplish the same thing, as it also provides arbitrary precision math.

Answer (score 0):

```
function logical_right_shift( $val , $shft ) {
    return floor(($val / pow(2,$shft)));
}

function logical_left_shift( $val , $shft ) {
    return ($val * pow(2,$shft));
}
```